# Susy adds strange characters into css

Tags: css, susy-compass, compass-sass

I have used the basic grid snippet and finally compiled the scss. Result looks great in browser.  Then I found some errors in css file that my Sublime Text editor highlighted.

e.g. for "@include container" susy creates following css:

```
  *zoom: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  _width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0%;
  padding-right: 0%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
```

As you see, there are two errors in the first and third line. There are a "*" and "_" signs. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

- Adding _ to attributes is a way to ensure they're ignored in IE
- Adding * to attributes gets IE to accept them and other browsers to ignore them

Answer (score 0):

Those are [legacy IE hacks](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters/).

- "`*property`" targets IE7 and below.
- "`_property`" targets IE6.

If you don't need legacy IE hacks, you can turn it off using the standard compass [support settings](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/support/):

```
$legacy-support-for-ie6: false;
$legacy-support-for-ie7: false;
```